# Android, PHP, HttpGet

Tags: php, android, json

I currently have a URL to a php file I wrote that produces the following (JSON string I believe)

```
{"id":"10","email":"test@uconn.edu","username":"test","bio":"I am not real","karma":"200","posted_jobs":"Posted job","accepted_jobs":"Accepted jobs"}
```

I need to fetch this in android studio... but I have tried to do so in many ways but no matter what the app crashes when I make an http request (from one of the many default JSONParser classes I found... I've tried different parser methods too but none work.)

Is there a special format I should be retrieving this with? I've honestly never spent as many hours on one problem as I have with this one. Getting super frustrated >:(

EDIT:
One of the methods I have tried to use

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url){
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
        is = httpentity.getContent();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");

            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jObj;

}
```

EDIT: debug log results

```
04-30 19:11:33.670  32306-32306/uconn.campusoddjobs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: uconn.campusoddjobs, PID: 32306
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1239)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:388)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:367)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
        at uconn.campusoddjobs.JSONparser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONparser.java:48)
        at uconn.campusoddjobs.Profile.<init>(Profile.java:39)
        at uconn.campusoddjobs.MyAccountFragment.onCreateView(MyAccountFragment.java:23)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is your Log saying? What kind of Exception do you get? By the way, there is a couple of helpful libraries out there for RESTful web services. Consider using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), it's pretty easy to use and saves you a lot of time.

Comment: Looks like the right idea though, what's the crash?

Comment: I made an edit with what shows in debug mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making your request on the main thread.
Network operation must not be made on the main thread because they block your user interface.

You may use an ASyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in order do to that.

Here is a tutorial: http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Comment: life saver... i knew it was something simple that an intelligent mind here could figure out. Now I am on to much more "difficult" problems like trying to get the info I carried in to properly display in a TextView XD... Thank you!